# SQLite Driver available with R's rgdal:writeOGR?

Tags: gdal, r

Does anybody know how I can get OGR's SQLite Driver to work with R's rgdal package?
When listing the drivers in R with the `ogrDrivers()` command the SQLITE driver is missing..

Comment: I assume this is on Windows? Compiling rgdal is hard on Windows, and if it's not in the CRAN binary you are out of luck. It's relatively straightforward on Linux though, so perhaps rephrase your question if that's an option. Otherwise you might request that CRAN support SQLite on the win-build, though licensing terms may be a complication.

Comment: @mdsumner, sorry, yes Windows. Thanks for clarification. Put it as an answer and I'll check it.